# fighting with radio button for boolean

Tags: angularjs

I'm unable to get my head around this, any idea on what am I doing wrong over here

```
<div class="radio-list">
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2" value="true" ng-model="event.active" />
  Yes </label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2" value="false" ng-model="event.active" />
  No </label>
</div>


  $scope.event.active = data.data[0].active ? "true" : "false";
```

Tried with 0, and 1 initially, then true and false, but still no sucess.

Edit (some more code).

```
result: function(data) {
    if(data.data.length > 0) {
        this.$scope.event.name = data.data[0].name; //works
        this.$scope.event.from = data.data[0].from; //works
        this.$scope.event.to = data.data[0].to; //works
        this.$scope.event.active = data.data[0].active ?  true : false; //doesnt work
        this.$scope.event.appId = data.data[0].appId;
        this.$scope.$apply();
        console.log(data.data);
        console.log(this.$scope.event.active, data.data[0].active);
    }
},
```

Comment: Would you test to see if this change works or not?   `$scope.event.active = data.data[0].active ? true : false;`

Comment: no, that didn't work either, not sure, what part am I missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't wrap it in quotes `"` its making it string

```
$scope.event.active = (data.data[0].active === 1) ? true : false;
```

by default value for radio will be `0` or `1`, but you can change it if like using `ng-value="true"`

```
  <input type="radio" 
      name="optionsRadios2" 
      ng-value="true" 
      ng-model="event.active" />
```

[Read more here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)

Here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5f3geefp/1/) you just needed `ng-value` here

Comment: I tried, both but no success, can you please create some demo fiddle

Comment: it's a bootstrap, with results updated from outside, editing with the code.

Comment: check now, i have created a fiddle with demo, if you can show what `data.data[0].active` is returning will be helpful

Comment: console statement for `console.log(this.$scope.event.active, data.data[0].active);` is returning  `true 1`

Comment: interesting, in your fiddle, both radio buttons are checked, I'm using chrome, and in safari it worked fine

Comment: same problem, the fiddle is broken in chrome but works in safari, (mine in neither)

Comment: is there a way to add conditional `checked` attribute to radio buttons?

Comment: mg-model will do it automatically for you, don't complicate it, angular will take care of checking on off the radio button according to the provided model data, 0 or 1, true or false

Comment: share console.log(data.data);

Comment: turns out that another framework was conflicting with radio buttons, it works now, but i still wonder why chrome doesn't work with your fiddle